# How do I inject CSS different css files based on the page. (Chrome Extension)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

So I'm working on a theme for google classroom and I want *a.css* to inject on https://classroom.google.com/u/0/h/* but

I want to use the same extension to inject *b.css* on https://classroom.google.com/u/0/a/*

How can I go about this?

Comment: Inject your css in your content script and you know to which  css to inject by the 'matches' in your manifest file

Comment: @OriEng I know how to do that alone, but with multiple css scripts depending on the page. I dont know

Comment: What you mean know how to do it alone? You mean that you know to inject one? Or what? Can you copy your manifest please